# How to import Weazyprint properly error showing list index out of range

Tags: python, django

I am trying to import Weazyprint but it is not working for some reason, I have followed the instructions from:

https://pypi.org/project/WeasyPrint/

https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#step-5-run-weasyprint

but still nothing is working, I am using Pycharm and it is showing underlined error: No module named weasyprint

I have `python -m pip install WeasyPrint`

but it doesn't seem to be reading it, although when I try to reinstall it an error saying it is already satisfied

Here is the views.py

```
import weasyprint

@staff_member_required
def admin_order_pdf(request, order_id):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order,ordered=True, id=order_id)
    html = render_to_string('pdf.html', {'order': order})
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="order_{}.pdf"'.format(Order.id)
    weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response,
                    stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0]+ 'blog/main.css')])
    return response
```

admin.py

```
def order_pdf(obj):
    return mark_safe('<a href="{}">PDF</a>'.format(reverse('store:admin_order_pdf', args=[obj.id])))


order_pdf.short_description = 'Order PDF'


class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', ... ,order_pdf]
```

In the admin page I am seeing the PDF icon but when I press it is returning this error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My question: How to properly install it so that it can be recognized? Is this error related to the installation?

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\store\views.py", line 593, in admin_order_pdf
    stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0]+ 'blog/main.css')])
```

***Update***:
I have added the static directory to my settings but now it is returning
Here is the static directory:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'blog/static')]
```

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Project\\blog/staticblog/main.css'
```

I want to know whats wrong to figure it out.

Comment: Have you defined `STATICFILES_DIRS` in `settings.py`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS

Comment: @Md.NahidurRahman I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the view.py to be like and it worked:

```
    weasyprint.HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response,
                    stylesheets=[weasyprint.CSS(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0]+ '/blog/main.css')])
```